# How to check using If else condition in render function to print friendly values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

how to check the condition in render function to print friendly names
example if (value =101) then "some text ", else if (value = 102) then "Another text" etc
Please check the code below what I am trying.

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IGetSpListsProps> {
return (
<div>
<ol>
{
this.state.sitecontents.map(function(mylists,mylistitemkey){
return(
<li>
  <span>{mylists.Title}</span> //here it will display list titles
  
  if({mylists.BaseTemplate} = {'101'} // basetemplate will return int number like 100, 101, 103 etc so checking the condition with 101
  {
    <p>{"Generic List template"}</p>
  }
  else if ({mylists.BaseTemplate} = {'102'}) {
    <p>{"Document List template"}</p>
  } else {
    <p>{"Custom template"}</p>
  })
  
  </li>);
  })
}</ol></div>
  );
```

{mylists.BaseTemplate} will return template number so i want to print friendly name to that template number, I am trying to print but its not expected. please check the output how its displaying
If we see the below screenshot the condition is considering as **simple text**

[image]

How to check condition using if else
Or is there any way to create a file/Json values and lookup from that file to get correspond friendly string?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the state? You can get the idea from [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `if - else` keywords inside JSX. You can use `if` and `else` and return different JSX or use `?:` inside JSX as follows

Change following

```
if({mylists.BaseTemplate} = {'101'} // basetemplate will return int number like 100, 101, 103 etc so checking the condition with 101
  {
    <p>{"Generic List template"}</p>
  }
  else if ({mylists.BaseTemplate} = {'102'}) {
    <p>{"Document List template"}</p>
  } else {
    <p>{"Custom template"}</p>
  })
```

to

```
<li>
  <span>{mylists.Title}</span>
  {
    mylists.BaseTemplate == '101' ? 
        <p>{"Generic List template"}</p> :
        mylists.BaseTemplate == '102' ? 
           <p>{"Document List template"}</p> :
           <p>{"Custom template"}</p>
  }
</li>
```

Comment: First of all really thanks @Mayank, still no luck if I directly use the above code it shows error like "This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'string' and '{ '101': any; }' have no overlap"  When I remove { } and just used only the code after the span tag, its okay means no error , code is reading like as usual string not like condition as I shared the above screen shot. what the error i am getting

Comment: If i remove the curly brackets then no error but still its reading like string the entire code don`t understand why not able to apply condition

Comment: What if I create file in the solution it self  and create json data with required data and refer/import this to lookup for string value data.  in that case how to lookup String/friendly names with base number